# emberjs using AND on querying from mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, ember.js, sails.js, sails-mongo

I'm working on an Emberjs application and I've got quite far with it
but i'm having an issue and I think that I've looked at every corner in the
web without finding the solution

Now my problem is that I have a dropdown that queries record on change "meaning" I have a "Dental" Department which contains "Braces" as a service
(service belongs to department) so when the user changes the dropdown option a query runs to filter the results again but within the results showing there is a text field which should be able to allow the user to search within the services shown accordingly to the selected department.

So far so good. The problem is that when the user starts typing to filter the data the condition in which services belongs to the selected department won't work any more so is there a way to use AND in my "Ember" controller to query records with more than one condition ?

Here is my Template

```
<div class="form-group">
  {{#power-select
    options=departments
    selected=selectedDepartment
    searchField="name"
    placeholder="Select Department..."
    onchange=(action (mut selectedDepartment))
    dropdownClass="in-modal-dropdown"
    renderInPlace=true
    as |department|
  }}
      {{department.name}}
  {{/power-select}}
 </div>
 {{#if selectedDepartment}}
 <hr />
  <div class="form-group has-feedback">
   {{input value=searchText class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Search Services" insert-newline="doSearch"}}
     {{#if searchText}}
       <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback"></i>
     {{/if}}
  </div>
  <br />
  {{#each departmentServices as |service|}}
    <button {{action 'selectService' service}} class="ux-product-override-for-request w-clearfix w-inline-block">
      <div class="ux-product-icon"></div>
      <div class="ux-product-title">{{service.name}}</div>
      <div class="ux-product-price">{{service.price}} RS</div>
     </button>
  {{/each}}
 {{/if}}
```

and my Controller

```
  store: Ember.inject.service(),
  departments: Ember.computed(function(){
    return this.get('store').findAll('department')
  }),
  departmentServices: Ember.computed('selectedDepartment', 'search', function(){
    if(this.get('search') == '' || this.get('search') == null){
      console.log(this.get('search'));
      return this.get('store').query('service', {
        where: {
          department: this.get('selectedDepartment.id')
        }
      })
    } else {
      return this.get('store').query('service', {
        where: {
          { department: { this.get('selectedDepartment.id')} }
          { name: { contains: this.get('search')} }
        }
      })
    }
  }),
  selectedDepartment: null,
```

Comment: Where are you getting data from mongodb?

Comment: return this.get('store').query('service', {
        where: {
          { department: { this.get('selectedDepartment.id')} }
          { name: { contains: this.get('search')} }
        }

Comment: i'm using sails-mongo

Answer (score 0):

`{{input value=searchText` - here you are using `searchText` but in `departmentServices` computed property you are using `search` but this is not the actual issue.

Issue is, `this.get('store').query` will return the `Promise` not the value so your implementation will not work out.(if you want to make it work you can try 3rd options `Special promise-backed objects` mentioned https://emberigniter.com/guide-promises-computed-properties/)

I will encourage you to introduce `setDepartmentServices` function which will query and update `departmentServices` property. and power-select for onchange instead of using the `mut` you can use `onchange = (action 'setSelectedDepartment')` and `searchText` input filed `doSearch` will call `setDepartmentServices`.
Here is the pseudo code,

```
setDepartmentServices() {
    //this will do query and will set the result in departmentServices property.
}
actions: {
    setSelectedDepartment(selectedDepartment) {
        this.set('selectedDepartment', selectedDepartment);
        //check if its ok to update departmentServices
        this.send('setDepartmentServices');
    }
    doSearch() {
        //check if its ok to update departmentServices
        this.send('setDepartmentServices');
    }
}
```